# How do I make Angular CLI ignore a custom folder for build

Tags: angular, build, angular-cli, node-modules

I needed to make a few changes to a library in `node_modules`. So I took the files from `node_modules` and moved them to a folder `app/custom_node`. I pointed all my files to use the library from the new path. I then deleted the reference from `project.json`.

I then tested the build using `ng build` everything was fine. I then ran the project using `ng serve` and it worked as expected.

The problem is, when I run the build for prod `ng build --prod` I get a ton of errors on the library that I copied into my `custom_node` folder.

Is there anyway to have the build ignore the `custom_node` directory?

I tried using `tsconfig` with `custom_node/**/*` in the exclude, but that did not work.